# htaccess / mod_rewrite / SSL | If: http off and (basket or order), 301 https, else 301 http

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl, https

I try to redirect to https (and back) if the user is in basketcase or in the order process.

I tried so much - but it doesn't work:

```
# if ssl off and basket|order -> https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?:basket|order)
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# elseif ssl on and !basket|order -> http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:basket|order)
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

### Sample URL's:

Wrong: http://www.example.com/basket.html
Correct: https://www.example.com/basket.html

The first (if) part alone works great - but together it's horrible!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try it this way. I don't think your condition is matching.

```
# if ssl off and basket|order -> https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(basket|order).html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# elseif ssl on and !basket|order -> http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(basket|order).html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Let me know now that works for you.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately as before! If alone works, but in conjunction with the elseif block it no longer works.

Comment: Clear your browser cache or try in another browser. I know that should work. I've tested it.

Comment: Ok, you are right! It work's - but not together with my other RewriteRules AFTER THAT and I don't know how they could make any problems - because of the L Flag.